# How to prevent auto form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following input box which takes input from barcode scanner.

```
 <form class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right" method="post" action="{{ url('updateInvoice') }}" id="invoice_update">
    <div class="form-group m-form__group">
       <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Search by item name or barcode</label>
       <input type="text"  autofocus class="form-control m-input" id="productSearch"  placeholder="Item name">              
    </div>
     <button type="submit" name="pdf" class="btn btn-success">Update & print
     </button>
</form>
```

After getting the input from barcode it does following operation (from the input it checks value from database and add to row)

```
$( "#productSearch" ).change(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
          type: "get",
          context: this,
          url: "{!! asset('searchByProductName') !!}",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { name:this.value },
          success: function(response)
            {
              if ($('#' + response.id).length !== 0)

              { $(this).val("").focus(); return false; }

             var markup = "<tr id="+response.id+"><input type='hidden' name='product_id[]'  value="+response.id+"><td><i class='flaticon-delete-1 delete-row' onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td><td>"+response.product_name+"</td><td>"+response.product_unit_price+"</td><td><input type='text' name='quantity[]' class='quantity' value='1'></td><td class='total'>"+response.product_unit_price+"</td><td>"+response.notes+"</td></tr>";  
              $("table tbody").append(markup); 
              $(this).val("").focus(); return false; 
              } 

        });

});
```

But the problem the form get auto submit ie, i can't add more than one value in the table. How do i prevent the form automatic submit so that more that one input can be taken with the above ajax code?

Comment: remove `type="submit"` from the button and add `onclick` javascript listner

Comment: @DeepakPatel that is not right option

Comment: what do you mean you can't add more than one value in the table?

Comment: whenever the input box filled with barcode scanner. the form get submitted. That's why i can't add more from the above input box

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the barcode scanner put the "enter key", but how about this one?

```
$("#form-id").on("submit", function(e) {
    if ($("#input-id(productSearch)").is(":focus")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the easiest way is to add a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" />
```

browser will auto submit if there is one input in a form.